# Getting no such directory file error when compiling

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega

I recently got my wifi module and connected it to my Uno. I am now trying to send a http request. I have the code that comes with the esp8266wifi library in which it demonstrates and gives an example on how to send a http request. This is the code:

[CODE.](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/examples/HTTPSRequest/HTTPSRequest.ino)

I am getting the following error

```
    Arduino: 1.8.4 (Windows 8.1), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

In file included from C:\Users\Yasmeen\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/ESP8266WiFi.h:33:0,

                 from C:\Users\Yasmeen\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_modified_sketch_200757\HTTPSRequest.ino:14:

C:\Users\Yasmeen\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/ESP8266WiFiType.h:26:19: fatal error: queue.h: No such file or directory

 #include <queue.h>

                   ^

compilation terminated.

exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.
```

Obviously it seems to be an file path error but I'm not sure why. I've imported the library through the Arduino IDE.. But maybe the way I aquired the library was wrong? What I did was download the esp8266wifi folder ([here](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries)) and zipped the file and imported it.. is that okay to do?

Answer (score 3):

The ESP8266WiFi library is for programming the ESP8266 directly. You are trying to compile source code for the ESP8266 for the Arduino UNO, that obviously won't work.

[A Beginner's Guide to the ESP8266](https://tttapa.github.io/ESP8266/Chap01%20-%20ESP8266.html)